# Repeating a method call

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am looking for the best way to do a repeating web call every few seconds. I have the web call already set up but I am unsure how to go about calling on a set time.

Comment: Have you looked into `Timers`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example how to setup a timer , also please note that the OnTimedEvent is on a diffident thread so if you want to pass parameters to your web service take this into consideration:

```
private static Timer _Timer;

public static void Main()
{
        // Create a timer with a 8 second interval.
        _Timer= new System.Timers.Timer(8000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        _Timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        _Timer.Enabled = true;

       // Start you other stuff here
 }

 private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
        // Call your web service here
 }
```